# assembler XOR encrypt/decrypt file

Tags: assembly, nasm, xor, encryption

Looking for a program written in assembler which will encrypt / decrypt files. I use NASM as a compiler. I found the sample code but it throws errors

```
encrypt_xor proc lpBuffor:dword, dwSize:dword, dwKey:dword

   mov eax,lpBuffor
   mov ecx,dwSize
   mov edx,dwKey

  next_byte:

   xor byte ptr[eax+ecx-1],dl
   dec ecx
   jne next_byte

   ret
```

encrypt _xor endp

I have error in:

```
 encrypt_xor proc lpBuffor:dword, dwSize:dword, dwKey:dword
```

and

```
 encrypt_xor proc lpBuffor:dword, dwSize:dword, dwKey:dword
```

error parser: instruction expected
and also here

```
xor byte ptr[eax+ecx-1],dl
```

error coma or end of line expected

What is wrong in this code?

Comment: Which CPU/Arch are you targeting? You can check out OpenSSL sources and/or AES-NI instructions (Sandybridge and higher)

Comment: quba88, please accept the answer given or state why it isn't acceptable for you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code you provided seems more like MASM syntax.
An equivilent NASM syntax can be something like this:

```
; void encrypt_xor(LPBYTE lpBuffor, DWORD dwSize, DWORD dwKey)
encrypt_xor:
  push    ebp 
  mov     ebp,esp 

  %stacksize flat
  %arg lpBuffor:dword, dwSize:dword, dwKey:dword

   mov eax,[lpBuffor]
   mov ecx,[dwSize]
   mov edx,[dwKey]

  next_byte:

   xor [eax+ecx-1],dl
   dec ecx
   jne next_byte

   mov esp, ebp
   pop ebp

   ret
```

There are a few things to note here. Use of *%stacksize* and *%arg* assumes a **cdecl** calling convention (i.e all parameters are passed on the stack). In NASM, this requires the a stack frame to be included (hence the *esp* and *ebp* statements).

One last note - if this code is shared, you should think about changing the name. The routine does not provide any kind of strong encryption and it's a bad idea to lull developers into a false sense of security.

Comment: dec ecx, jne next_byte *is* an optimisation...  Loop is more readable, but slower on modern processors.

Comment: @BrianKnoblauch Really? I'd appreciate seeing the proof/demonstration of two instructions "dec ecx, jne next_byte" being faster than a single Loop instruction.

Comment: "loop" is to all intends and purposes obsolete. I wouldn't even expect it to stick around for much longer. An actual optimization here would be to use SSE2 to xor 16 bytes at once (with some fixup for the unaligned parts of course), or at least 4 at once in a GPR

Comment: I think LOOP will stick around for the foreseeable future.  It's hard to toss an instruction that's still in use.  Yep, people still use it.  People that are going for readability instead of speed.  I believe it's a byte shorter then the dec/jne sequence as well.  Dropping it would break a lot of code...  Backwards compatibility is why we're all still stuck with x86/x64 and weren't able to make the jump to a better architecture yet.

Comment: I stand corrected. The Intel Optimization Manual also lists LOOP as having a relatively high latency.

Comment: Hi @adelphus, could you edit your answer to reflect the change of mind regarding the loop statement, not all readers will get to the end of the comments (and thanks for the answer of course).

Comment: The comment about optimisation has been stripped - I guess it was never really pertinent to the OP anyway.